# Matching everything but a time range using regex

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression that matches time ranges:

```
(([0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\s*)-(\s*[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]))
```

However, I need a regex that can extract everything except the time range in a string such as: `"June 12, 2015 13:30 - 14:00"` (i.e., `"June 12, 2015"`), but I can't seem to do it.

I tried using both a lookahead and lookbehind, such as the following, but they don't seem to work (at least for me ;).

```
(?<!(([0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\s*)-(\s*[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9])))
```

Comment: Why not use the regex that works as a way to substitute the matching string with an empty string? What's the application? I only ask because regexes that include NOTs are usually more costly than simple string substitution.

Comment: @OozeMeister: it's not always the case and most of the time it is because this kind of patterns are badly written (using stupidities like `(?:(?!thestringiwanttoavoid).)+`)

Comment: The application converts dates and times provided by a user on the command line to different timezones. As long as only a single date and/or time is provided, my app works fine. My problem is with time ranges (as in OP). Although I can deal with the time range with the regex above, I'd like to deal with the date (if provided) separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @OozeMeister for the hint. I'm coding in Ruby, and code substitution is the solution.

```
t = "June 12, 2015 13:30 - 14:00"
reg = /(([0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\s*)-(\s*[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]))/
date = t.gsub(reg, '')
puts date
```

Output: `"June 12, 2015 "`

Comment: You could add `\s` at the beginning of the regex to get rid of the unwanted space at the end of the string. Also, you might want to accept your answer.

Comment: As a bit of a noob, I have to wait 2 days before I can accept the answer.